# Is $\sqrt[n]{x} = 0$ an algebraic equation?

Tags: functions, polynomials

According to the definition for algebraic equation on wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_equation, it is an equation of the form $P(x,y) = 0$. But I've read that an algebraic equation is one that involves the four elementary operations plus roots finitely many times, here for reference: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-algebraic-and-transcendental-function. So, can algebraic equation have roots or not?

Comment: I think that you are mistaking algebraic functions for algebraic equations. [Algebraic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function) are functions that are solutions of a [polynomial equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_equation), a.k.a. algebraic equation. A polynomial/algebraic equation has the form of a polynomial, which consists in a finite sum of a variable raised to a non-negative integer power multiplied by a coefficient.

Comment: Can you comment on the answer here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-algebraic-and-transcendental-function? Here it says that an algebraic function involves roots too. I'm aware that algebraic functions are solutions to a polynomial equations but how can roots be involved here? I don't know where is my understanding wrong. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Think on the quadratic formula, for quadratic polynomials...

Comment: But the quadratic formula is a constant function that solves the quadratic polynomial equation which is an algebraic equation. There aren't any roots in this algebraic equation, yet the answer says that there can be roots in the algebraic equations.

Comment: I posted an answer regarding this point. I think that introducing polynomials of several variables can give you a better insight. Take a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [algebraic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_equation) is an equation in the form
$$
P(x,y,\cdots) = 0,
$$
in which $P$ is a polynomial in the variables $x,y, \cdots$. An [algebraic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function) is a solution of a polynomial equation, e.g.
$$
P(x,y) = x^2y(x)^2 + xy(x) + x = 0,
$$
which has as solutions
$$
y = -\frac{-x + \sqrt{x^2-4x^3}}{2x^2} \ \ \mathrm{and} \ \ y = -\frac{-x - \sqrt{x^2-4x^3}}{2x^2}.
$$
See that you have both rational and negative powers.

Any polynomial in the form
$$
P(x) = a_n x^n + \cdots a_1 x + a_0 = 0
$$
has a constant solution, which is also an algebraic function.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Still I am troubled by the answer given here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-algebraic-and-transcendental-function. There are roots in the algebraic function that is the solution to the equation, but the algebraic equation is just a multivariate polynomial equal to zero. The answer on the link says that the algebraic equations involve roots too. So I suppose its wrong to say that because by the definition, a polynomial cannot have fractional exponents. Or I'm missing something again?

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. I think it's safe to say that the answer is _wrong_ when it affirms that an algebraic equation can involve roots. I prefer the definition in Wikipedia, that treats algebraic and polynomial equations as synonyms. From the content in Wikipedia, and from my answer, you can see that _algebraic functions_ can involve combinations of rational powers (e.g. $\sqrt{x}$, $1/x$), while _algebraic equations_ involves only integer powers.

Comment: Thanks for the great help. Maybe the answer was referring to the situation when you exchange the expression by which the function is defined in the algebraic equation. I think then it can be okay to say that.

Comment: @LearningMath You are welcome. However, I really think it is a mistake. If you take the solution for $y$ that we found in the answer, for example, and plug it into the original algebraic equation and develop the calculations, you must find $0=0$. It would be nonsense to solve the equation for $x$ after plugging $y(x)$ in the equation because it is valid for any $x$, as long that $y$ is the given by the solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It doesn't make sense to search for $x$ in $0=0$. Thanks for the wonderful answer again.